# Or Condition in Linear Programming with GLPSOL AMPL/MathProg

Tags: linear-programming, ampl, glpk, mathprog

I want to write an optimization model which selects the lesser of the two tasks, depending upon some constraint.

```
minimize obj: (doT1 * T1) + (doT2*T2) + (additional variables)
```

Now, T1 and T2 represent duration of tasks, and doT1 represents flag to do these tasks. I want this optimization to select only one of them if needed.

When I put the constraint

```
s.t. c15: 0<= doT1 <= 1;
s.t. c15: 0<= doT2 <= 1;
```

I get an error message which in glpsol which says that multiplication of linear forms not allowed.

Is it possible to express the OR condition in linear programming?

Answer (score 1):

`gplsol` is most likely complaining about the product of variables `doT1 * T1` and `doT2 * T2`.

I'm assuming that `doT1` and `doT2` are binary variables, and `T1` and `T2` are continuous variables (representing the duration of tasks). (Note that this means you will have to use a mixed integer programming solver rather than a pure linear programming solver. You might also want to try using a powerful MIP solver like [Gurobi](http://www.gurobi.com)).

You can construct your model by rewriting your constraints and objective as

```
  minimize  T1 + T2 + (additional variables)

   st        T1 <= UT1*doT1
             T2 <= UT2*doT2
             doT1 + doT2 <= 1
             doT1, doT2 binary
             (plus any additional constraints)
```

where `UT1` is an upper bound on the duration of task `T1` and `UT2` is an upper bound on the duration of task `T2`.  If `doT1 = 0` then `T1 <= 0`, so the task will not be completed. If `doT1 = 1`, then `T1 <= UT1`, meaning that task `T1` is allowed to take some duration. The same holds for `T2`.

The OR condition is expressed by the constraint `doT1 + doT2 <= 1`. This constraint means that `doT1` and `doT2` cannot both be 1. That is only one job can be selected. Note that the `<=` constraint also allows you to not perform either task. If at least one task must be completed, you want to use the constraint `doT1 + doT2 == 1`.